# Heisenbergs Uncertainty Principle in different intertial frames

Tags: special-relativity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Say there is a single particle in a box. If we switch to a different inertial frame (without the box) travelling close to the speed of light we see the box get smaller. At a high enough speed the uncertainty principle will cause the particle to have a high momentum, perhaps even high enough to break the box.This is obviously incorrect but can anyone explain why the above argument fails?

Comment: Relative momenta of the particle and the box are not that high, their difference counts. Furthermore, their wavefunctions are related in both reference frames as well, so if one of them has high momentum, the other one has it too. Btw, it looks like that this is not well understood so far (e.g. [relativistic uncertainty principle](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-equation-for-relativistic-uncertainty-principle)).

Answer (score 1):

If by 'we' you mean 'you and the box' then travelling at relativistic speeds will change **nothing for you**, you wouldn't notice anything. Only if you kept the box stationary and accelerated the particle to relativistic speeds would it maybe be able to break out of the box, depending on the potential barrier of the box.